# Mounting a weird CD image

Tags: disk-image, bin-cue-image

I have a CD image from an old game that I would like to mount in a virtual drive using software like Virtual CloneDrive, Daemon Tools etc. The disc is a mixed mode CD, so it has 1 data track and multiple audio tracks.

The image is a `.bin`/`.cue` pair, however it is somewhat non-standard. The bin file only contains the data track. The audio tracks are stored as `.ogg` files in a folder called `music`, which the `.cue` file references using a relative path.

```
FILE "game.bin" BINARY
  TRACK 01 MODE1/2352
    INDEX 01 00:00:00
FILE "music\game_01.ogg" MP3
  TRACK 02 AUDIO
      INDEX 01 00:00:00
FILE "music\game_02.ogg" MP3
  TRACK 03 AUDIO
      INDEX 01 00:00:00

... (more music tracks)
```

So it seems that this cue sheet  is trying to create the music tracks out of real files in the system. There is no problem mounting this image in DOSBox, and ImgBurn reads it without any problems, however, neither is able to mount them to a real virtual drive. Virtual CloneDrive cannot mount `cue`/`bin` pairs (however I **was** able to mount just the `bin` file, which is only the data track), and Daemon Tools gives an error when I tell it to mount the `cue`.

I thought about converting this image` pair to another format, but I don't know about any program that can do that. UltraISO promises such functionality, but wasn't able to correctly read my image.

The only solution I can think of is to burn the image to a real disc and then create an image with a different format out of it, but unfortunately my computer doesn't have an optical drive.

So can anybody help me mount such an image?

Answer (score 0):

If it's really old it was probably created using Nero Burning ROM or Alcohol 120% which commonly used bin / cue file pairing.  Give a try with WinCDEmu https://wincdemu.sysprogs.org/.  Otherwise, try a trial version of PowerISO.

Alternately, you might be able to use Image Burn to burn the cue and bin files to an ISO that you can then mount - https://www.imgburn.com/

Comment: WinCDEmu throws an error. PowerISO reads the image, but when throws an error when trying to mount it. I tried converting it to a proper cue/bin, but it only copied the data track. As for the last method, ISO files can only store 1 data track, nothing else, but my image is a mixed mode CD.